# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './src/assets/images/logo.png'

Tags: javascript, typescript, expo, relative-path, nrwl-nx

In my app.json I have this configuration for the icon:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "icon": "./src/assets/images/logo.png"
  }
}
```

The icons path is => `apps/my-app/src/assets/images/logo.png`

The app.json path is => `apps/my-app/src/app.json`

I get the error that the path I provide inside app.json in expo.icon is wrong. I know this is stupid but can you please help me out to find which is the relative path??
I have also tried: `assets/images/logo.png`, `./assets/images/logo.png` and `../assets/images/logo.png`.